# Control the size of a Legend

Tags: plotting, legending

Given the following plot

```
Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,0,2\[Pi]},Epilog->Inset[Framed[LineLegend[{Directive[Black],Directive[Red,Dashed]},{"Phase=1, BG=A","Phase=2, BG=O"}],RoundingRadius->5],Scaled[{0.625,0.3}]]]
```

How can we make the legend size smaller?

Comment: does `size=.2; Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Rasterize[
    Framed[LineLegend[{Directive[Black], 
       Directive[Red, Dashed]}, {"Phase=1, BG=A", "Phase=2, BG=O"}], 
     RoundingRadius -> 5], RasterSize -> 500], 
   Scaled[{0.625, 0.3}], {0.5, 0.5}, Scaled[size]]]` work in your version/OS?

Comment: It does. Thank you @kglr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`Rasterize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) the first argument of `Inset` and use the fourth argument to set the size:

```
size = .3;
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[Rasterize[Framed[LineLegend[{Directive[Black], Directive[Red, Dashed]}, 
       {"Phase=1, BG=A", "Phase=2, BG=O"}], RoundingRadius -> 5], 
    RasterSize -> 500], Scaled[{0.625, 0.3}], {0.5, 0.5}, Scaled[size]]]
```

[image]